# How to find pantone shades of a particular color?

Tags: pantone

A client came to me with their logo for a campaign and wanted me to do the collaterals. I did a few thing for her. Now she wants me to give her the names of pantone colors matching the exact two colors in her logo. How do I find the pantone shades for them?
Please help! 
Thanks

Comment: The best way to choose would be with a Pantone Color Book. Sounds like to me they don't have Pantone colors chosen yet, so you have the luxury to choose them for her, whether with the book or digital.

Answer (score 2):

Official Pantone Color Finder:

www.pantone.com/color-finder

In the long term you might want to get yourself a paper guide. But they are expensive ...
www.pantone.com/fashion-home-interiors/paper-products

Maybe you could go to a local print shop or design studio in your area and ask them to have a look at their paper guide.

**Update:**
As @Rafael pointed out in the comments, the web picker from Pantone doesn't accept RGB or HEX. So here is:
**How to pick a Pantone color in Photoshop:**

1. Select your color with the color picker and click 'Color Libraries':

[image]

2. From the 'Book' dropdown menu select your preferred Pantone scale.

[image]

3. Pick the Pantone color you like best. (Photoshop will suggest one.)

Comment: The problem with that page is that you can not input a hex, rgb cmyk values. Only another Pantone color. Another thing is that if you input one color that has no exact match, it spits back a ton of diferent options.

Comment: @Rafael True. I didn't notice that. Thanks for pointing it out. I have added a different method in my answer ...